# Formating numbers in javascript, without altering

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am looking for a jQuery plugin, or a regex-solution, to format numbers in JavaScript, without altering, rounding or adding zeros. A number goes in, and comes back formatted according to three rules:
 - Thousands separator
 - Number of decimals
 - Desired separator

Here is some examples of what I am looking for:

```
Thousands: Comma, Decimals: 0, Separator: Point
Input: 1000 » Output: 1,000
Input: 100000 » Output: 100,000

Thousands: Space, Decimals: 2, Separator: Comma
Input: 1000 » Output: 10,00
Input: 100000 » Output: 1 000,00

Thousands: Comma, Decimals: 1, Separator: Point
Input: 1000 » Output: 100.0
Input: 100000 » Output: 10,000.0
```

Comment: without changing ... the result?

Comment: I changed the headline to "...without altering". All the solutions I have found adds two zeros when decimals are defined. I would like a solutions that dosen't add any numbers at all. Only separators.

Comment: How to format in case of a negative number?

Comment: how 1000 can be formatted to 10,00? There is something I don't get

Comment: @Gerard Nothing should change, besides adding separators (space, comma or point, for thousands and decimals). Negative number should continue to be negative.

Comment: @RegisPortalez It is a long story, but I am working with financial tables online (obviously) and they are often published in different languages, so in order to make the "translation" fast and easy, I would like to offer a tool for just that.

Comment: @errand All there is, it seams. I've tried everything Google has to offer in the first five pages of search result. This is the best, so far, but when I define decimals, this solution will add zeros: https://github.com/customd/jquery-number

Comment: Please add the code you tried to the question.

Comment: @HenrikLindqvist What you are doing is an unusual thing to do, usually one formats existing decimal numbers such as 1.234 to, let's say, 2 decimal places so it becomes 1.23, or 4, so it becomes 1.2340, that's why zeroes are added. All you need to do is divide the number before formatting. For example, if you want 10000 being formatted as 10.00, you would need to divide it by 100 so it becomes 10 before formatting it to 10.00.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have tried a lot of different plugins, so I haven't really written any code for this. But when I tried "jquery-number", I did this: var value = $.number( value, decimals, separator, thousands ); If value == 100, the result with two decimals will be 100.00.

Comment: @CherryDT Hmm. You are on to something here... Thanks. I will try that out.

Answer (score 2):

Try this function:

```
function format(prop) {
    prop.input = String(prop.input);
    var input = prop.input, decimals = '';
    if (prop.decimals) {
        input = prop.input.slice(0, -prop.decimals);
        decimals = prop.separator + prop.input.slice(-prop.decimals);
    }
    return input.replace(/(?!^)(?=(...)+$)/g, prop.thousands) + decimals;
}
```

Example:

```
format({
    input: 100000,
    thousands: ' ',
    decimals: 2,
    separator: ','
});
// "1 000,00"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it. But, if I input 100 I'll get "1,1" back, when it should be 1,00. 1200 becomes 12,12.

Answer (score 0):

I made a quick function for you.

```
function lindqvistFormat(input, thouSep, decimals, decSep) {
    var inStr = (input * (input < 0 ? -1 : 1)).toFixed(0);
    while(inStr.length < decimals + 1) inStr = "0" + inStr;
    var leftPart = inStr.substr(0, inStr.length - decimals), rightPart = decimals ? decSep + inStr.substr(-decimals) : "";
    return (input < 0 ? "-" : "") + leftPart.replace(/(?!^)(?=(...)+$)/g, thouSep) + rightPart;
}
```

Example: `lindqvistFormat(-1234567890, " ", 2, ".")` will result in `-12 345 678.90`.

It also handles values with less digits than the requested number of decimals, and so on.

I know it's not very self-explanatory how it works and it uses a few shortcuts, but it works, and I don't have much time at the moment to explain how. I decided to post it anyway because it does, in fact, provide a solution to your problem.

**EDIT:** user6188402's regex is actually much more clever than my solution and doesn't require the `extLeftPart` I had, so I changed my solution to work similar to his. Credits for the regex part there go to user6188402, therefore. (My old solution was having an `extLeftPart` which is padded with dummy chars to make a length dividible by 3, then use `Array.prototype.join(extLeftPart.match(/.{3}/g), thouSep)` and then remove the padding again at the end.)